# FilesProcessor with asset filed in custom content elelemt

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

in the following script:

```
tt_content.myFCE {
    dataProcessing {
        10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
        10 {
            references.fieldName = image
            as = files
        }
        20 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
        20 {
            references.fieldname = assets
            as = myFiles
        }
    }
}
```

the first part (index 10) works but the second (index 20) doesnt. I get an empty array. It seems that the FilesProcessor is not able to access the images which are stored in assets.

Is there a possibility to fetch the assets from the field assets?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it work only with 20 and removing 10?

Comment: you are aware that `fieldname` isn't equal to `fieldName`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bernd Wilke wrote it in his comment: there is a typo in fieldname - it should be fieldName ... i was totaly blind, didn`t see it until his comment. What a shame ... :-) After correcting the typo all works exactly as expected.